# How do I correctly configure PutMongo to do an upsert?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, apache-nifi

I'm trying to configure the PutMongo (1.7.0) processor to do an upsert into a collection. I get this error: [image: I get this error]

This is my PutMongo config:

[image]

This is what the incoming flowfile looks like:

```
{"_id": {"compositeOne":"co", "compositeTwo": "ctr"}, "value": true}
```

The flowfile has the following _id attribute:

```
{"compositeOne":"co", "compositeTwo": "ctr"}
```

The TEST collection has a document with exactly the same content as the flowfile.

I expected the update query to go through, as I can see nothing wrong with it, instead I get the above error.

I already tried to reproduce this in the mongo shell, using this query:

```
    db.TEST.update({_id: {"compositeOne":"co", "compositeTwo": "ctr"}}, {_id: {"compositeOne":"co", "compositeTwo": "ctr"}, "value": true}, {upsert: true});
```

This query produces no error. How can I configure the PutMongo processor so that the query doesn't produce the error above?

Comment: are you trying to insert the same values again? you mentioned "The TEST collection has a document with exactly the same content as the flowfile"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to **modify _id key** which is like a **Primary key**.

You cannot update **_id key** as the error description says you are trying to modify **immutable** object.

Regarding the below query

```
db.TEST.update({_id: {"compositeOne":"co", "compositeTwo": "ctr"}}, {_id: {"compositeOne":"co", "compositeTwo": "ctr"}, "value": true}, {upsert: true});
```

when you try to perform  upsert in mongodb which already has same document,mongo just ignores it and doesn't update any new data.assume that you are trying to update same data mongo just finds the match but doesn't update anything as shown below.

**Note: "nUpserted" :0**

[image]

Comment: How am I trying to modify my _id key? I'm not trying to do that. I'm trying to perform an upsert operation. If I supply an _id object that's already present in the collection, I expect mongo to do a update operation on that key. If it's not present, I expect it to do an insert. That's what an upsert is, is it not? Maybe the NiFi processor is the problem...